# Flutter Text field not updating after writing something more than or less than the initial value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have 2 TextFormFields and for each of them i have an initial value, but when i type something on the text field and add or remove something from the initial value and press enter or done on the keyboard the text editing controller doesnt update. i tried looking for some ways to fix it with using Form and then the key but it didnt work for me maybe i didnt know how to implement it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
TextEditingController editedFirstName =
                          TextEditingController()..text = data3.firstName;
                      TextEditingController editedLastName =
                          TextEditingController()..text = data3.lastName;

                      Future<void> putAccountData() async {
                        SharedPreferences prefs =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        String? authorization =
                            prefs.getString('authorization');
                        var url =
                            'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/employees/account';
                        Map payload = {
                          "firstName": editedFirstName.text,
                          "lastName": editedLastName.text,
                        };
                        try {
                          final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(url),
                              headers: <String, String>{
                                'authorization':
                                    authorization ?? basicAuth.toString(),
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                              },
                              body: jsonEncode(payload));
                        } catch (er) {}
                      }

                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: width,
                            height: height / 1.9,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                width: 3,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "First Name:",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const Spacer(),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: width / 2.5,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: TextFormField(
                                            textAlignVertical:
                                                TextAlignVertical.center,
                                            controller: editedFirstName
                                              ..selection =
                                                  TextSelection.collapsed(
                                                      offset: data3
                                                          .firstName.length),
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              contentPadding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10.0,
                                                      horizontal: 10.0),
                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                    color: Colors.red,
                                                    width: 1),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 17,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                            // inputFormatters: [
                                            //   LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)
                                            // ],
                                            validator: (value) {
                                              if (value == null ||
                                                  value.isEmpty) {
                                                return 'Name is required';
                                              }
                                              return null;
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Last Name:',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const Spacer(),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: width / 2.5,
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          controller: editedLastName
                                            ..selection =
                                                TextSelection.collapsed(
                                                    offset:
                                                        data3.lastName.length),
```

Comment: That's because you are resetting the text field of the controller everytime. move the ..text = data3.lastName to the controller declaration or in the initValue. And also I don't know what you are trying to achieve, it would be good if you explain that further.

Comment: full code is in here >> https://pastebin.com/r5aG9t9d

Comment: Please take a moment to explain what you want to achieve in the post, so we can help you. the code is not enough. Thanks!

Comment: ok so i want to have an initial value on the text field, when the user presses to write something on the text field, i want it to work that he can change the initial value to whatever he want, so i can send what he wrote on the post request, updated the code btw

Comment: Where is the initial value coming from is it from fetchData call ?

Comment: yes it is coming from api

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the flutter docs on [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) say

> A TextEditingController can also be used to provide an initial value for a text field. If you build a text field with a controller that already has text, the text field will use that text as its initial value.

To set the initial value for a text input in Flutter set it in the controller on initialization:

```
TextEditingController textControllerWithDefault = TextEditingController(text: 'hello world');
```

In your case that should look like:
`TextEditingController editedFirstName = TextEditingController(text: data.firstName)`.

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: Try moving the `..selection =` part up as a property in the `editedFirstName = TextEditingController(selection: ...` declaration too and setting `controller: editedFirstName` without anything else on the widget